# How to save settings of gui with pyqt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

With pycharm I created a small gui with pyqt6 and I would like to save the gui settings in an ini file.

I used a venv with the latest pyqt6

```
Python 3.10.12

PyQt6-Qt6-6.6.1 
PyQt6-sip-13.6.0 
pyqt6-6.6
```

I have a problem to save the settings with the close event and I could need a hint.

**Error message during closing of the gui:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../Test_ui/main.py", line 18, in closeEvent
    self.saveSetting()
  File "/home/.../Test_ui/main.py", line 23, in saveSetting
    self.settings.setValue("Debug", self.ui.checkBox.isChecked())
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'settings'
```

It's not clear for me why the object MainWindow has no attribute 'settings'.

**Added Code for minimal, reproducible Example:**

**main.py**

```
import sys
from distutils.util import strtobool

from PyQt6.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from ui.test import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test Tool")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.saveSetting()
        print("Exit")

    def saveSetting(self):
        print("Save settings")
        self.settings.setValue("Debug", self.ui.checkBox.isChecked())

    def loadSettings(self):
        self.settings = QSettings("./TestTool.ini", QSettings.Format.IniFormat)
        try:
            print("Load settings...")
            self.ui.checkBox.setChecked(bool(strtobool(self.settings.value("Debug"))))
        except:
            pass

def main_GUI():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    return app, window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app, window = main_GUI()
    rc = app.exec()
    print("App end is exit code {}".format(rc))
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**ui/test.py**

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui/test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt6 UI code generator 6.6.1
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 190, 84, 20))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 19))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
```

Comment: It's simply because the code never calls `loadSettings`. (PS: it's also very important that you read the [PyQt6 QSettings guidance](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/pyqt_qsettings.html). The correct way to retrieve a boolean value would be `self.settings.value("Debug", False, type=bool)`, where the second argument is an appropriate default).

Comment: Thx. After adding `self.loadSettings()` in the `__init__` function, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ekhumoro

Update in **main.py** the function `def __init__(self)` with the call `self.loadSettings()`

And corrected the read out of the setting.

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from ui.test import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test Tool")
        self.loadSettings()


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.saveSetting()
        print("Exit")

    def saveSetting(self):
        print("Save settings")
        self.settings.setValue("Debug", self.ui.checkBox.isChecked())

    def loadSettings(self):
        self.settings = QSettings("./TestTool.ini", QSettings.Format.IniFormat)
        try:
            print("Load settings...")
            self.ui.checkBox.setChecked( self.settings.value("Debug", False, type=bool) )
        except:
            pass

def main_GUI():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    return app, window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app, window = main_GUI()
    rc = app.exec()
    print("App end is exit code {}".format(rc))
    sys.exit(rc)
```